# Populating viewModel array with model

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

I have a model called `Product` and `viewModel` called `productViewModel`.
The `Product Model` has few properties, but for the example let's say it has only `name` and `price`.

This is the product:

```
struct product {

  private let name: String
  private let price: Float

}
```

I create a viewModel like this:

```
struct productViewModel {
private let product: Product
private let isFavorite: Bool

init(product: Product, favorite: Bool = false) {

    self.product = product
    self.isFavorite = favorite

    }
}
```

As you can see, the `productViewModel` has the `isFavorite` field which the model does not have.
I have a function that fetches `Product`s from the server.
I want to populate the a `viewModel` array with it, and check for each product if it is in the `favorites table` (a local table on the device itself, using `SQLite`)

I thought about something like this:

```
private func populateViewModel() {
    for p in popularProducts {
        let favorite = favoritesTable.contains(p)
        let model = ProductViewModel(product: p, isFavorited: favorite)
        viewModels.append(model)
    }
}
```

and after I get a products list from the server, to call this `populateViewModel` function, but it seems really not efficient, but I couldn't think of anything else.

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking, but can't you add `isFavorite` to your model struct?

Comment: I don't think so. I mean, technically I can, but since isFavorite can be true or false depending on the user, I don't really want to add it in the database. the name and price for example, are universal, and should be displayed the same on every device, the isFavorite is not, so I don't really want to do it.

Comment: OK, makes sense. So when you are saying "it seems really not efficient", what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @koen It seems like this is too much to do, every time I fetch the data, to run a loop to populate another array, and then I should also make sure that the array got populated and is not empty when I try to use it, etc.

Comment: If you are concerned about constantly accessing your SQLite table, maybe the owner of the `populateViewModel` can keep a local variable, or possibly store it the info in `UserDefaults`.

Comment: @koen that is exactly my concern, because, now, after fetching the data, I need to go over the fetched products array, and for each one of those I need to check if the user favorited that product, and create the viewModel. seems way too much job and I'm afraid it will be slow.

Comment: You can always use Instruments to check for bottlenecks. Maintaining local arrays instead of constantly fetching the data seems the way to go.

Comment: @koen yep, thank you, I do want to also cache the data of course so I won't have to always fetch it, but still thinking it's too much work. I will work on it, and see if it slows down the app.

Answer (score 2):

```
private func populateViewModel() {
    for p in popularProducts {
        if p.isFavorite{ //it is favorited
            let model = ProductViewModel(product: p, isFavorited: favorite)
            viewModels.append(model)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up creating the model array, and populate it. I set wrote the isFavorite part in the model and use it whenever I need.